# matlab change settings of uigetdir

Tags: matlab, user-interface

how can I change the size and the font color of the line: "Please choose the directory of the camera"?

```
camera_folder_name = uigetdir('C:\', 'Please choose the directory of the camera');
```

it's so small :/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In short: You cannot change it, at least officialy*

Matlab merely calls Windows API functions that open file dialog. The size of the font is determined in Windows Users preferences. There might be something [undocumented](http://www.undocumentedmatlab.com), but as usual, use these things with caution.